# Deleting all subfolders except one recursively

Tags: bash, find, rm

I would like to create a one-liner, that would delete subfolders recursively, preserving the newest directory per subfolder. This probably can be achieved by chaining some find and rm commands, but I can't get my head around how to do this. I can not trust mtime on this as some are of them are messed up. All directories on 3rd level are named in date format like this: year, month, day, hour (24h), minute, second.

**Example folder structure**

```
parent/a/2020-09-14_104423
parent/a/2020-08-14_230000
parent/a/2020-07-14_100000
parent/b/2020-07-14_140000
parent/b/2019-06-14_104423
parent/b/2019-05-14_104423
parent/c/2020-08-14_100000
parent/c/2019-06-14_174423
parent/c/2019-05-14_104423
...
```

**Result**

```
parent/a/2020-09-14_104423
parent/b/2020-07-14_140000
parent/c/2020-08-14_100000
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a working one-liner, accounting only for the described directory names:

```
for dir in parent/*/; do printf "%s\n" "$dir"/*/ | sort -r | tail -n +2; done
```

will list the directories to delete, and

```
for dir in parent/*/; do printf "%s\n" "$dir"/*/ | sort -r | tail -n +2 | xargs rm -rf; done
```

will delete them.